# Linear gradient not fixed when screen size changes

Tags: html, css, vue.js, responsive-design, frontend

I have a linear gradient in my background:

https://prnt.sc/9mmoSmAazP8A

The problem is that when the screen size changes, my gradient is not starting at Point 0:

https://prnt.sc/S9fGUR2Ta3l9

How can I assure that the gradient starts at point 0 all the time, no matter the screen size? (Mobile screens not included)

```
body #screen-background{
    
    background: linear-gradient(-5deg, #DFDFDD 10%, #3D4A6D 11%);

}
```

This is what I want. If screen size changes, the angle could change, no problem. I want just that the gradient begins and ends like this:

```css
.linear-background{
background: linear-gradient(-5deg, #DFDFDD 10%, #3D4A6D 11%);
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="linear-background"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet and check that it demonstrates the problem. What do you want it to look like on wider viewports where it will hit the bottom of the element to the right a bit? Are you certain you want a fixed angle? If so you’ll need a tall element on wide devices.

Comment: @AHaworth thanks. Edited. But the code and the result are the same from my question and image posted before

Comment: So the question remains - what do you want it to look like on different viewport sizes?

Comment: @AHaworth being X and Y axes of a graph, regardless of the size of the screens, the gradient must start at X = 0. Always.

Right now, if I increase the screen size, the gradient starts slightly in front. For example, at X = 10. But I dont want that. I want the gradient to start always at point X = 0, independently of the screen size.

Angle can vary, slightly if it helps

Comment: Using an angle won’t work, it’s simply geometry that is against you. Look into clip path perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try putting `position:relative;`
on the `.linear-background` selector, like this:

```
.linear-background{
background: linear-gradient(-5deg, #DFDFDD 10%, #3D4A6D 11%);
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but still no results

Comment: .linear-background{
background: linear-gradient(-5deg, #DFDFDD 10%, #3D4A6D 11%);
height: 200px;
width: 200px; position:relative;
}

Comment: I forgot to add it 

Comment: no problem. I understood that and I added the position relative, like you said, and still no result

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know clip paths
This is really very usefull
Thanks @mxritz and @AHaworth

https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/